# arch linux - bluetooth mouse not automatically connecting

Tags: arch-linux, bluetooth

I have recently installed arch linux and added the relevant bluetooth packages

```
sudo pacman -S --noconfirm bluez bluez-utils
sudo modprobe btusb
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth.service
sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service
```

I have a Logitech MX Master 3, when I'm logged in and turn on the mouse I can manually connect it to the laptop just fine. When I now turn the mouse on and off again it will also auto-connect.
However, when I put the laptop to sleep or it boots up and then log in, then mouse will no longer auto-connect. I then have to turn it off and on again and it will auto-connect.

I can see the following log entries in `journalctl`

```
Nov 20 10:48:26 mordor bluetoothd[925]: src/profile.c:record_cb() Unable to get Hands-Free Voice gateway SDP record: Host is down
Nov 20 10:48:31 mordor bluetoothd[925]: profiles/input/hog-lib.c:set_report_cb() Error setting Report value: Unexpected error code
Nov 20 10:48:31 mordor kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0005:046D:B023.000E: Device not connected
```

Is there a way to get the mouse auto-connect after coming back from sleep or a boot?

Comment: What's happen if you just restart `bluetooth.service` instead of turn off/on the mouse? Does it reconnect automatically?

Comment: @mattia.b89 No it doesn't connect then either

Comment: Does it happen with any other peripheral too?

Comment: I have a keyboard with bluetooth connected as well and that one auto-connectes fine, just the mouse doesn't

Comment: So it looks like a device-specific issue...

Comment: I have the same problem (Arch, MX M3) and I found out it takes a while (approx. 30 sec) to reconnect the mouse without the need to turn it off and on. It began a month ago.  But this is not the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think your mouse goes into sleeping mode (with a quick google search it I can see Logitech MX Master 3 does that) and Arch loses it.

There is a way to disable auto-suspend altogether on the device by leaving it on "always", [see this discussion in the forums.](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1178070#p1178070)

User "brebs" advised another user to make a USB udev rule through systemd for his mouse (by creating-editing /etc/udev/rules.d/91-local.rules):

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{product}=="Razer Abyssus", ATTR{power/control}="on"
```

Reload the rule to take effect:

```
udevadm control --reload
```

Brebs even provided a script to check but in your case you could try the above, switching your device's detected name  of course and see if it works.

Comment: This seems to apply to USB mice, not bluetooth mice.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with the same mouse,

make sure to configure auto power in `bluetooth.conf`:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Bluetooth#Auto_power-on_after_boot/resume

install `tlp` package for power management scripts and mask the `rfkill` service:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/TLP#Radio_Device_Wizard_(tlp-rdw)

Answer (score -1):

Check your Power management first, such as powertop or tlp.

My old solution is add a udev rule.
Because of powertop.service, I can not set power/control.

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=2042206#p2042206

/etc/udev/rules.d/99-logitech.rules

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{product}=="G502 HERO Gaming Mouse", ATTR{power/autosuspend}="-1"
```

But I think you can try reboot your device by udev
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Udev#Triggering_events

Comment: Same as first answer.

Comment: @number9 I don't think so, my answer show a solution for wrong udev setting because of other APP.